# Multilayer Seq2Seq model with LSTM in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, seq2seq, encoder-decoder

I was making a seq2seq model in keras. I had built single layer encoder and decoder  and they were working fine. But now I want to extend it to multi layer encoder and decoder.
I am building it using Keras Functional API.

## Training:-

## Code for encoder:-

```py
encoder_input=Input(shape=(None,vec_dimension))
encoder_lstm=LSTM(vec_dimension,return_state=True,return_sequences=True)(encoder_input)
encoder_lstm=LSTM(vec_dimension,return_state=True)(encoder_lstm)
encoder_output,encoder_h,encoder_c=encoder_lstm
```

## Code for decoder:-

```py
encoder_state=[encoder_h,encoder_c]
decoder_input=Input(shape=(None,vec_dimension))
decoder_lstm= LSTM(vec_dimension,return_state=True,return_sequences=True (decoder_input,initial_state=encoder_state)
decoder_lstm=LSTM(vec_dimension,return_state=True,return_sequences=True)(decoder_lstm)
decoder_output,_,_=decoder_lstm
```

## For testing :-

```py
encoder_model=Model(inputs=encoder_input,outputs=encoder_state)
decoder_state_input_h=Input(shape=(None,vec_dimension))
decoder_state_input_c=Input(shape=(None,vec_dimension))
decoder_states_input=[decoder_state_input_h,decoder_state_input_c]
decoder_output,decoder_state_h,decoder_state_c =decoder_lstm #(decoder_input,initial_state=decoder_states_input)
decoder_states=[decoder_state_h,decoder_state_c]
decoder_model=Model(inputs=[decoder_input]+decoder_states_input,outputs=[decoder_output]+decoder_states)
```

Now when I try to increase the no. of layers in the decoder for training then training works fine but for testing it dosen't works and throws error.

Actually the problem is when making it multi layer i had shifted the `initial_state` to a middle layer which used to be specified at the end.So
when I am calling it during testing, it is throwing errors.

```py
RuntimeError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("input_64:0", shape=(?, ?, 150), dtype=float32) at layer "input_64".The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []
```

How should I pass the `initial_state=decoder_states_input` which is for the input layer so that it doesn't throws error.
How should I pass the `initial_state=decoder_states_input` in the end layer for for the first Input layer??

## EDIT:-

In that code I have tried to make multiple layers of decoder LSTM. But that's giving error.
When working with single layer.The correct codes are:-

## Encoder(Training):-

```py
encoder_input=Input(shape=(None,vec_dimension))
encoder_lstm =LSTM(vec_dimension,return_state=True)(encoder_input)
encoder_output,encoder_h,encoder_c=encoder_lstm
```

## Decoder(Training):-

```py
encoder_state=[encoder_h,encoder_c]
decoder_input=Input(shape=(None,vec_dimension))
decoder_lstm= LSTM(vec_dimension, return_state=True, return_sequences=True)
decoder_output,_,_=decoder_lstm(decoder_input,initial_state=encoder_state)
```

## Decoder(Testing)

```py
decoder_output,decoder_state_h,decoder_state_c=decoder_lstm( decoder_input, initial_state=decoder_states_input)
decoder_states=[decoder_state_h,decoder_state_c]
decoder_output,decoder_state_h,decoder_state_c=decoder_lstm (decoder_input,initial_state=decoder_states_input)
decoder_model=Model(inputs=[decoder_input]+decoder_states_input,outputs=[decoder_output]+decoder_states)
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, the code you've given works. Could you please add the code that does not work to clarify what the problem is?

Comment: Actually that was the wrong code, because I have added multiple layers of Decoder there. I have added the correct for single layer.How should that code be extended to multiple layers of LSTM

Comment: Did you manage to get this working? I'm having same problem.

Answer (score 14):

EDIT - Updated to use the functional API model in Keras vs. the RNN

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, LSTM, Dense, RNN
layers = [256,128] # we loop LSTMCells then wrap them in an RNN layer

encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None, num_encoder_tokens))

e_outputs, h1, c1 = LSTM(latent_dim, return_state=True, return_sequences=True)(encoder_inputs) 
_, h2, c2 = LSTM(latent_dim, return_state=True)(e_outputs) 
encoder_states = [h1, c1, h2, c2]

decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None, num_decoder_tokens))

out_layer1 = LSTM(latent_dim, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
d_outputs, dh1, dc1 = out_layer1(decoder_inputs,initial_state= [h1, c1])
out_layer2 = LSTM(latent_dim, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
final, dh2, dc2 = out_layer2(d_outputs, initial_state= [h2, c2])
decoder_dense = Dense(num_decoder_tokens, activation='softmax')
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(final)


model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs)

model.summary()
```

And here is the inference setup:

```
encoder_model = Model(encoder_inputs, encoder_states)

decoder_state_input_h = Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
decoder_state_input_c = Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
decoder_state_input_h1 = Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
decoder_state_input_c1 = Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
decoder_states_inputs = [decoder_state_input_h, decoder_state_input_c, 
                         decoder_state_input_h1, decoder_state_input_c1]
d_o, state_h, state_c = out_layer1(
    decoder_inputs, initial_state=decoder_states_inputs[:2])
d_o, state_h1, state_c1 = out_layer2(
    d_o, initial_state=decoder_states_inputs[-2:])
decoder_states = [state_h, state_c, state_h1, state_c1]
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(d_o)
decoder_model = Model(
    [decoder_inputs] + decoder_states_inputs,
    [decoder_outputs] + decoder_states)

decoder_model.summary()
```

Lastly, if you are following the Keras seq2seq example, you will have to change the prediction script as there are multiple hidden states that need to be managed vs. just two of them in the single-layer example. There will be 2x the number of layer hidden states

```
# Reverse-lookup token index to decode sequences back to
# something readable.
reverse_input_char_index = dict(
    (i, char) for char, i in input_token_index.items())
reverse_target_char_index = dict(
    (i, char) for char, i in target_token_index.items())

def decode_sequence(input_seq):
    # Encode the input as state vectors.
    states_value = encoder_model.predict(input_seq)

    # Generate empty target sequence of length 1.
    target_seq = np.zeros((1, 1, num_decoder_tokens))
    # Populate the first character of target sequence with the start character.
    target_seq[0, 0, target_token_index['\t']] = 1.

    # Sampling loop for a batch of sequences
    # (to simplify, here we assume a batch of size 1).
    stop_condition = False
    decoded_sentence = ''
    while not stop_condition:
        output_tokens, h, c, h1, c1 = decoder_model.predict(
            [target_seq] + states_value) #######NOTICE THE ADDITIONAL HIDDEN STATES

        # Sample a token
        sampled_token_index = np.argmax(output_tokens[0, -1, :])
        sampled_char = reverse_target_char_index[sampled_token_index]
        decoded_sentence += sampled_char

        # Exit condition: either hit max length
        # or find stop character.
        if (sampled_char == '\n' or
           len(decoded_sentence) > max_decoder_seq_length):
            stop_condition = True

        # Update the target sequence (of length 1).
        target_seq = np.zeros((1, 1, num_decoder_tokens))
        target_seq[0, 0, sampled_token_index] = 1.

        # Update states
        states_value = [h, c, h1, c1]#######NOTICE THE ADDITIONAL HIDDEN STATES

    return decoded_sentence


for seq_index in range(100):
    # Take one sequence (part of the training set)
    # for trying out decoding.
    input_seq = encoder_input_data[seq_index: seq_index + 1]
    decoded_sentence = decode_sequence(input_seq)
    print('-')
    print('Input sentence:', input_texts[seq_index])
    print('Target sentence:', target_texts[seq_index])
    print('Decoded sentence:', decoded_sentence)
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.  Can you confirm for me if creating two LSTMCells and wrapping them in an RNN layer as you have done is functionally the same as creating two LSTM layers where the first layer feeds into the second?

Comment: This wont work if you wish to use the CuDNN layers as they don't have an offered Cell equivalent in keras.

Comment: I updated the answer to use the functional API with multiple LSTM layers. Tested it and it appears to translate well

Comment: thank you @JeremyWortz Ive been struggling with this for a month and this finally solved it. It appears my primary mis step was not accounting for the extra layer states in inference.

Comment: This has been hugely helpful!  I've modified your code to work for depth-n rather than a fixed 2, so it loops through a latent_dims array, the length of which defines the number of stacked LSTM layers.  I'll be done with using it by the end of tomorrow, I'll make sure to clean it up and post it afterwards (tomorrow)!

PS: Your 'layers' array isn't actually used, and both layers are using the same latent_dim variable.

Comment: This is quite helpful, though shouldn't the second/higher encoder layer state be the state input for the first/higher decoder layer? The second decoder layer is the lower layer, providing input to the Dense output layer, so I would expect it to receive state from the encoder layer of the same level - one away from the input/one away from the output. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding some aspect of this approach.

Answer (score 5):

I've generalized Jeremy Wortz's *awesome* answer to create the model from a list, 'latent_dims', which will be 'len(latent_dims)' deep, as opposed to a fixed 2-deep.

Starting with the 'latent_dims' declaration:

```
# latent_dims is an array which defines the depth of the encoder/decoder, as well as how large
# the layers should be.   So an array of sizes [a,b,c]  would produce a depth-3 encoder and decoder
# with layer sizes equal to [a,b,c] and [c,b,a] respectively.
latent_dims = [1024, 512,  256]
```

Creating the model for training:

```
# Define an input sequence and process it by going through a len(latent_dims)-layer deep encoder
encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None, num_encoder_tokens))

outputs = encoder_inputs
encoder_states = []
for j in range(len(latent_dims))[::-1]:
    outputs, h, c = LSTM(latent_dims[j], return_state=True, return_sequences=bool(j))(outputs)
    encoder_states += [h, c]

# Set up the decoder, setting the initial state of each layer to the state of the layer in the encoder
# which is it's mirror (so for encoder: a->b->c, you'd have decoder initial states: c->b->a).
decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None, num_decoder_tokens))

outputs = decoder_inputs
output_layers = []
for j in range(len(latent_dims)):
    output_layers.append(
        LSTM(latent_dims[len(latent_dims) - j - 1], return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
    )
    outputs, dh, dc = output_layers[-1](outputs, initial_state=encoder_states[2*j:2*(j+1)])


decoder_dense = Dense(num_decoder_tokens, activation='softmax')
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(outputs)

# Define the model that will turn
# `encoder_input_data` & `decoder_input_data` into `decoder_target_data`
model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs)
```

For inference it's as follows:

```
# Define sampling models (modified for n-layer deep network)
encoder_model = Model(encoder_inputs, encoder_states)


d_outputs = decoder_inputs
decoder_states_inputs = []
decoder_states = []
for j in range(len(latent_dims))[::-1]:
    current_state_inputs = [Input(shape=(latent_dims[j],)) for _ in range(2)]

    temp = output_layers[len(latent_dims)-j-1](d_outputs, initial_state=current_state_inputs)

    d_outputs, cur_states = temp[0], temp[1:]

    decoder_states += cur_states
    decoder_states_inputs += current_state_inputs

decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(d_outputs)
decoder_model = Model(
    [decoder_inputs] + decoder_states_inputs,
    [decoder_outputs] + decoder_states)
```

And finally a few modifications to Jeremy Wortz's 'decode_sequence' function are implemented to get the following:

```
def decode_sequence(input_seq, encoder_model, decoder_model):
    # Encode the input as state vectors.
    states_value = encoder_model.predict(input_seq)

    # Generate empty target sequence of length 1.
    target_seq = np.zeros((1, 1, num_decoder_tokens))
    # Populate the first character of target sequence with the start character.
    target_seq[0, 0, target_token_index['\t']] = 1.

    # Sampling loop for a batch of sequences
    # (to simplify, here we assume a batch of size 1).
    stop_condition = False
    decoded_sentence = []  #Creating a list then using "".join() is usually much faster for string creation
    while not stop_condition:
        to_split = decoder_model.predict([target_seq] + states_value)

        output_tokens, states_value = to_split[0], to_split[1:]

        # Sample a token
        sampled_token_index = np.argmax(output_tokens[0, 0])
        sampled_char = reverse_target_char_index[sampled_token_index]
        decoded_sentence.append(sampled_char)

        # Exit condition: either hit max length
        # or find stop character.
        if sampled_char == '\n' or len(decoded_sentence) > max_decoder_seq_length:
            stop_condition = True

        # Update the target sequence (of length 1).
        target_seq = np.zeros((1, 1, num_decoder_tokens))
        target_seq[0, 0, sampled_token_index] = 1.

    return "".join(decoded_sentence)
```

Comment: Hi, why might there be `return_state`  in `LSTM(latent_dims[len(latent_dims) - j - 1], return_sequences=True, return_state=True)`, if we're not uing dh and dc?